# Bash script for change strings in variables

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two variables in bash:

in the first variable, the field separator is (,) 
in the second variable, the field separator is also (,)

in the first variable named `VAR1` I have:

```
Maria Debbie Annie,Chewbakka Zero,Yoda One,Vader 001
```

in the second variable named VAR2:

```
"number":"11112",Maria Debbie Annie
"number":"11113",Maria Debbie Annie Lisa
"number":"33464",Chewbakka Zero
"number":"22465",Chewbakka Zero Two
"number":"34534",Christine Ashley
"number":"45233",Yoda One
"number":"45233",Yoda One One
"number":"38472",Susanne Ann
"number":"99999",Vader 001
"number":"99991",Vader 001 001
"number":"99992",Vader 001 002
```

The desired output in variable VAR3:

```
"number":"11112","number":"33464","number":"45233","number":"99999"
```

So basically i need to change the names in the output from some name to `"number":"somenumber"` the same order as in the first variable.
What is also important that there are very similar strings so 
`Yoda One != Yoda One One` also `Chewbakka Zero` is not equal `Chewbakka Zero Two`.

`VAR2` contains much more lines than listed, I just wanted to show the script needs to find exact matches between `VAR1` and `VAR2`. 
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I concur with @kvantour . In addition your syntax for VAR2 seems to change at end from using comma as delimiter to colon. Was that intentional? I'd advise you to take a look at cut. https://ss64.com/bash/cut.html

Comment: ok, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out..

```
> echo "$VAR1"
Maria Debbie Annie,Chewbakka Zero,Yoda One,Vader 001
> echo "$VAR2"
"number":"11112",Maria Debbie Annie
"number":"11113",Maria Debbie Annie Lisa
"number":"33464",Chewbakka Zero
"number":"22465",Chewbakka Zero Two
"number":"34534",Christine Ashley
"number":"45233",Yoda One
"number":"45233",Yoda One One
"number":"38472",Susanne Ann
"number":"99999",Vader 001
"number":"99991",Vader 001 001
"number":"99992",Vader 001 002
> export VAR1A=$(echo $VAR1| sed 's/,/$\|/g' | sed 's/$/\$/g')
> echo "$VAR1A"
Maria Debbie Annie$|Chewbakka Zero$|Yoda One$|Vader 001$
> echo "$VAR2"  | egrep "$VAR1A" | awk -F"," ' { printf("%s,",$1)} END { printf("\n") } ' | sed 's/.$//g'
"number":"11112","number":"33464","number":"45233","number":"99999"
>
```

Comment: egrep, awk, 3 sed ?, only awk is needed : VAR3=$(echo "$VAR2" | awk -F, -v a="$VAR1" 'BEGIN{d=split(a,b,",")}{for(i=1;i<=d;i++)if($2==b[i]){c=c sep $1;sep=FS}}END{print c}');echo "$VAR3"